# problem installing pytorch=1.6.0 and torchvision=0.7.0

Tags: pytorch, conda, torchvision

I am trying to set up the environment for a machine learning tool and it requires pytorch=1.6.0 and torchvision=0.7.0.
When i try to run

conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 -c pytorch 
it says packages not found in the channels (i have already added conda-forge)

Originally, the program requires python 3.7, but it seems to be no longer available and I saw a question previously succeed with using python 3.8. I set up the environment with the python 3.8 but it still doesnt seem to work. I am on the osx-arm64 platform.

Comment: Please add output of `conda info` to the question body. Possibly you are on a platform that doesn't have Python 3.7 support (e.g., **osx-arm64**).

Comment: I am on osx-arm64, does it also not support python 3.8?